# C++ game not time responsive to keys

Tags: c++

I am making Pacman in C++ with the Ncurses library. I am able to move Pacman with my code, but it takes a lot of time to switch between different directions. For instance, when Pacman is moving left and I press the right arrow key, it takes some time before it starts moving right.

```
 if (ch==KEY_LEFT)
 {
    int b,row,column;
    getyx(stdscr,row,column);
    for (b=column;b>=0;b-=1)    //loop to move the pacman left until it hits the wall
    {

     mvprintw(row,b,">");  //print the ">" symbol
     refresh();
     waitf(0.2);
     attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));      //this pauses the game for 1 second
     mvprintw(row,b,">");
     attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
     refresh();
     waitf(0.2);
     mvprintw(row,(b),"O");  //showing the open mouth of pacman
     refresh();
     waitf(0.2);
     attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));a
     mvprintw(row,(b),"O");

      attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));

      int h=0;
      h=getch();

      if (h!=KEY_LEFT)
      {
          break;
      }
  }
}
 right=getch();
 loop for right in an if condition
 up=getch();
 loop for up in an if condition
 down=getch();
 loop for moving down in an if condition
```

I have done the same thing for right, up, and down. Also, I have introduced new variables before every if statement to store the value of getch().

Comment: "a lot of time to switch"...what's "a lot"? Your own code has comments saying "this pauses for 1 second". If your "a lot" is "1 second", then there's your answer.

Comment: What happens on the screen when it takes that time? Is it still drawing something, i.e., animating?

Comment: You're not relying on key-repeat to make pacman continue moving, are you?  That would be against the spirit of pacman, and also maybe be responsible for the delay in him 'getting moving'.

Comment: it keeps on moving to the left side even when i press right key.

Comment: and it's 0.1 second not 1.sorry

Comment: can u tell me another way of doing it which might work??I have o get another key inpu inside the for loop so that if I press any other key,it changes direcion

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps the waitf(0.2) that causing the program to, um, wait before reading more keys?  You might consider interrupting the wait if there's input... you could use a timed select for that instead.

Comment: what do u mean by a timeed select??

Comment: see this example: [stdin select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360660/using-select-system-call-for-listening-on-stdin-and-the-server) also look up API reference on select and you can see you make it wait for a specific amount of time instead of forever.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put everything in the keyboard routine. It slows everything down.

Try     `if (ch==KEY_LEFT) go_left=true` then go do all that stuff in a function outside of the key processing rouine.

And `go_left==true` remains `true` until `ch==KEY_RIGHT` has been pressed, then `go_left=false`.

Sample game structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream> 

//#include "gamestuff.h"

using namespace std;


#define KB_ESCAPE 27
#define KB_UP 72
#define KB_DOWN 80
#define KB_LEFT 75
#define KB_RIGHT 77
#define KB_F8 66


int keypress=0;
bool go_left=false;
bool go_right=false;
bool go_up=false;
bool go_down=false;

void game_menu();
void keyboard_stuff();
void graphics_stuff();
void game_loop();


int main()
{
 game_menu();
 game_loop();

 return 0;
}

void game_menu()
{
    cout<<"Pacman Game  \n";
    cout<<"  \n";
    cout<<"[1] Resume Game  \n";
    cout<<"[2] Save Game  \n";
    cout<<"[Esc] Exit Game  \n";
    cout<<"  \n";
}


void keyboard_stuff()
{
    if (kbhit())
      {
            keypress = getch();
            //cout<<"KB_code = "<<KB_code<<"\n";

            switch (keypress)
            {

                case KB_ESCAPE:



                break;

                case KB_LEFT:
                           //go_left
                    go_left=true;
                    go_right=false;

                break;

                case KB_RIGHT:
                           //go_right   
                    go_left=false;
                    go_right= true ;

                break;

                case KB_UP:
                           //go_up  
                    go_up=true;
                    go_down=false;

                break;

                case KB_DOWN:
                           //go_down  
                    go_up=false;
                    go_down=true;

                break;

            }        

      }
}

void graphics_stuff()
{

    //put all graphics and draw stuff here

    if(go_left)
    {
        //Update  direction etc


    }

    if(go_right)
    {
        //Update   direction etc


    }

    if(go_up)
    {
        //Update   direction etc


    }

    if(go_down)
    {
        //Update   direction etc


    }

    //draw pacman stuff right here after the above

}

void game_loop()
{

   while(keypress!=KB_ESCAPE)
   {

     keyboard_stuff();
     graphics_stuff();

   }

}
```